# Email eye tracking

Tags: email, user-research, eye-tracking

I would like to perform eye tracking on a set of email templates, aimed at understanding which template performs the best overall and also breaking down the audience by few demographic dimensions.

Is there any paper/website that I can read on the most scientific approach to that or do you have any experience to share?

Comment: I conducted an eye-tracking study during my bachelor thesis a few month ago, so I sure might have experience to share. However it's a little bit difficult just to write and hope that it will help you. Could you be more specific? What do you want to know? My fellow students asked me several times about eye-tracking because they wanted to conduct a study themselves. After a clearing conversation, every time it turned out, that eye-tracking wasn't the right tool :) So first of all: Are you sure, that eye-tracking is the right tool?

Answer (score 3):

Here some Literature about Eye-Tracking:

- Duchowski, Eye Tracking Methodology: Theory and Practice, Springer
  2007 (This explains the technical and scientifical approach behind the eye-tracking method in it's full scope. There's even a description of how to build your own linux interface to a tracking device)
- Nielsen/Pernice, Eyetracking Web Usability, New Riders 2010 (This shows the approach and results of a large scaled usability study performed with the eye-tracking method)
- Yarbus, Eye movements and vision, 1967 (This is the "root" literature about eye movement measurement itself, i.e. the very famous and often used picture [The Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aYarbus_The_Visitor.jpg) is cited from this book)

There is a lot more, but it's very specific on a theme (like perception in marketing etc.pp.), so I didn't mention it.

Also there are online ressources of eye-tracking studies that are very specific, but might also help i.e. about forms:

http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2006/07/label-placement-in-forms.php

http://www.cxpartners.co.uk/cxblog/web_forms_design_guidelines_an_eyetracking_study/

Comment: It would be great if you can summarize those papers since that would provide more context

Comment: @mervinj done ;-)